# ndb structured/localstructured property 1mb limit per property or containing entity?

Tags: google-app-engine, properties, google-cloud-datastore

how is the 1mb entity size limit applied to structured/localstructured property in ndb?

can each (sub)property be up to 1mb in size or does their size count against the containing entities limit?

Answer (score 2):

The StructuredProperty's properties are really just properties of the top-level entity, but with special names that ndb knows what to do with (you can see this in the Datastore Viewer), so they count against the limit of the containing entity.